# Modulus of continuity of exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

From Intro to Calculus & Analysis II/1 by Courant & John.

> Find the modulus of continuity $\delta = \delta(\epsilon,x,y)$ for $f(x,y)=\sqrt{1+e^{xy}}.$

By the definition of continuity as presented in the book, if $f(x,y)$ is continuous at a point $Q(\xi,\eta)$ within its domain, then $\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists \delta \gt 0$ such that for all $P(x,y)$ in the domain of $f(x,y)$ for which  $ \sqrt{(x-\xi)^2+(y-\eta)^2}\lt \delta, |\sqrt{1+e^{xy}}-\sqrt{1+e^{\xi \eta}}|\lt \epsilon$.

I tried many ways but couldn't get $(x-\xi)^2$ or $(y-\eta)^2$ out of the given function. I even discussed with a friend but still have no idea. Any help would be highly appreciated. Here are my attempts:

$|\sqrt{1+e^{xy}}-\sqrt{1+e^{\xi \eta}}| = \sqrt{2+e^{xy}+e^{\xi \eta}-2\sqrt{(1+e^{xy})(1+e^{\xi \eta})}} $, here the argument of the outer square root is justified by A.M-G.M. inequality. Applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to $(1+e^{xy})(1+e^{\xi \eta})$ yields $(1+e^{xy})(1+e^{\xi \eta})\ge (1+\sqrt{{e^{xy+\xi \eta}}})^2$, hence $|\sqrt{1+e^{xy}}-\sqrt{1+e^{\xi \eta}}| \le \sqrt{2+e^{xy}+e^{\xi \eta}-2(1+\sqrt{{e^{xy+\xi \eta}}})}$.

If the C-S inequality is applied in a slightly different way, I have $(1+e^{xy})(e^{\xi \eta}+1)\ge (\sqrt{e^{\xi \eta}}+\sqrt{e^{xy}})^2 $ and hence  $|\sqrt{1+e^{xy}}-\sqrt{1+e^{\xi \eta}}| \le \sqrt{2+e^{xy}+e^{\xi \eta}-2(\sqrt{e^{\xi \eta}}+\sqrt{e^{xy}})}$

Then I could not proceed anymore.

Comment: This is an ugly problem, no matter what. But have you tried the usual approach of estimating $|\sqrt a-\sqrt b|$ by multiplying and dividing by $\sqrt a+\sqrt b$? It'll be easy to give a lower bound on the denominator.

Comment: Is the lower bound of the denominator $|\sqrt{1+e^{xy}}+\sqrt{1+e^{\xi \eta}}|\ge 1+e^u$ where $ u=max\{xy,\xi \eta\}$?

Comment: Your bound can't involve the varying point. I was thinking just $2$.

Comment: Hmm you're right I could(and should) just use 2